# Bulk Azure AD Update

Tags: powershell, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I have written a script to update the users' contact information in Azure AD. The CSV I'm using is an export from our local AD. I found some examples as a starting place and this is what I have hacked out ...

```
Start-Transcript "transcript.log"

# Connect to AzureAD
Connect-AzureAD

# Get CSV content
$CSVrecords = Import-Csv userexport.csv -Delimiter ","

# Create arrays for skipped and failed users
$SkippedUsers = @()
$FailedUsers = @()

# Loop trough CSV records
foreach ($CSVrecord in $CSVrecords) {
    $upn = $CSVrecord.samaccountname + "@daytonrogers.com"
    $user = Get-AzureADUser -Filter "userPrincipalName eq '$upn'"
    if ($user) {
        $command = "Set-AzureADUser -ObjectID $($user.objectid) "
        if ($CSVrecord.title) {$command = "$command -jobtitle '$($CSVrecord.title)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.department) {$command = "$command -department '$($CSVrecord.department)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.office) {$command = "$command -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName '$($CSVrecord.office)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.officephone) {$command = "$command -TelephoneNumber '$($CSVrecord.officephone)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.fax) {$command = "$command -FacsimileTelephoneNumber '$($CSVrecord.fax)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.mobilephone) {$command = "$command -Mobile '$($CSVrecord.mobilephone)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.streetaddress) {$command = "$command -streetaddress '$($CSVrecord.streetaddress)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.city) {$command = "$command -city '$($CSVrecord.city)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.state) {$command = "$command -state '$($CSVrecord.state)'"}
        if ($CSVrecord.postalcode) {$command = "$command -postalcode '$($CSVrecord.postalcode)'"}
        Write-Information $command
        try{
            $command
        } catch {
            $FailedUsers += $upn
            Write-Warning "$upn user found, but FAILED to update."
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "$upn not found, skipped"
            $SkippedUsers += $upn
        }
}
Stop-Transcript
```

It runs and builds the command just fine. However, none of the users get updated. If I copy / past the command from the transcript.log file, it works. It just does not work if I run the script from the PowerShell command line.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Outputting a command string isn't going to call it. You need to invoke it somehow. You could try with the call operator `& $command`.

Comment: I thought the same thing and found Invoke-Command and tried that but it did not do the trick.

I'll try yours.

Comment: I went back and put the '&' in and that did seem to make the script execute the command. All of them failed the try / catch, though. I took one from the trascript.log and copy pasted it to the command line and it worked. Any idea of how I can make the script output the reason the try failed?

Comment: I see the issue `&` can't parse strings. So you want to be able to see the command before it is run and then run it?

Comment: I don't know of a way to do this without using `Invoke-Expression`, which should never be used.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using AADConnect?

Comment: Yes, there is a reason we are not, yet, using AADConnect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating command strings and then executing them is going to lead to bad practices I think. You will have to resort to `Invoke-Expression`. That is something we want to avoid. I would build a hash table with your parameters and use [splatting.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-7) From that, you can build your command string to send to the information stream. See below for an example.

```
if ($user) {
    $command = "Set-AzureADUser"
    $params = @{}
    $params.ObjectID = $user.objectid
    if ($CSVrecord.title) {$params.jobtitle = $CSVrecord.title}
    if ($CSVrecord.department) {$params.department = $CSVrecord.department}
    if ($CSVrecord.office) {$params.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName = $CSVrecord.office}
    if ($CSVrecord.officephone) {$params.TelephoneNumber = $CSVrecord.officephone}
    if ($CSVrecord.fax) {$params.FacsimileTelephoneNumber = $CSVrecord.fax}
    if ($CSVrecord.mobilephone) {$params.Mobile = $CSVrecord.mobilephone}
    if ($CSVrecord.streetaddress) {$params.streetaddress = $CSVrecord.streetaddress}
    if ($CSVrecord.city) {$params.city = $CSVrecord.city}
    if ($CSVrecord.state) {$params.state = $CSVrecord.state}
    if ($CSVrecord.postalcode) {$params.postalcode = $CSVrecord.postalcode}
    Write-Information "$command $($params.GetEnumerator() |% {"-{0} '{1}'" -f $_.Key,$_.Value})"
    & $command @params
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @AdminOfThings. That got the script working and I learned something very valuable.